# Prove all the roots of a given polynomial lie in the disk with radius $2$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, polynomials, complex-numbers, absolute-value

I need to show that the roots of the  polynomial $z^5-z^4+15$ are in the disk $|z|<2$. But how do I do this? Am I supposed to compute all the roots?

Comment: This looks like an exercise on Rouche's theorem.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I haven't studied this theorem yet

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the triangle inequality we obtain:
$$|z|^5=|z^4-15|\leq|z|^4+15,$$
which gives $|z|<2.$

Because by  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs

the equation $$x^5-x^4-15=0$$ has one positive root and since $2^5-2^4-15>0$ and $1^5-1^4-15<0$,

we see that the positive root of the last equation is later than $2$.

Comment: how does it give |z|<2?

Comment: I added something. See now.

Answer (score 3):

If $|z|\ge2$, then the triangle inequality says that
$$
\begin{align}
|z^5-z^4+15|
&\ge|z|^4|z-1|-15\\[6pt]
&\ge|z|^4(|z|-1)-15\\[6pt]
&\ge16\cdot(2-1)-15\\[6pt]
&=1
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, $|z|\lt2$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $|-z^4+15|\leq |z|^4+15\leq 31<|z|^5$ when $|z|=2$, and so it follows from Rouche's theorem that $z^5-z^4+15$ and $z^5$ have the same number of zeros in the disk $|z|<2$, namely $5$.

Answer (score 0):

Set $\gamma(z)=-z^4+15$ and $f(z)=z^5$. For $\vert z\vert=2\,$ we have $\vert \gamma(z)\vert \leq 2^4+15=31<\vert 2^5\vert=32=\vert f(z)\vert$. By [Rouché's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem) the number of roots of $f$ in $\vert z\vert<2\,$ $(=5)$ concides with the ones of $z^5-z^4+15\,$ in $\vert z\vert<2\,$. Therefore, $\,z^5-z^4+15\,$ has $5$ roots in $\vert z\vert<2\,$; being $5$ the total number of roots of  $z^5-z^4+15\,$ in $\mathbb{C}$, then the given polynomial has all its roots in the disk $\vert z\vert \leq2$.